# Error when I execute a recursive query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, heroku, mariadb

I have the following query:

```
with recursive dates as (
            select curdate() as dte, 1 as lev
            union all
            select dte - interval 1 day, lev + 1
            from dates
            where lev < 7
           )
      select DATE_FORMAT(d.dte, '%d') AS date, count(distinct c.id) AS cards, count(distinct mc.id) AS people_cards
      from dates d 
      left join
           cards c
           on c.publicated = 1 and
              c.publication_date >= d.dte and
              c.publication_date < d.dte + interval 1 DAY
      left join
           people_cards mc
           on mc.publicated = 1 and
              mc.publication_date >= d.dte and
              mc.publication_date < d.dte + interval 1 day
      group by d.dte
```

This query works in my localhost, but when I deploy my project in *heroku*, this query doesn't work. When I execute it in my SQL Client, I get the following result:

[image]

But in my localhost, I get this result:

[image]

In my local, I'm using `MariaDB 10.5`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK you need MySQL 8 or newer for recursive queries. Which version are you running on heroku?

Comment: I think 5.5.6 version

Comment: Then that is most likely your problem, seems 8.0 or later is required. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: I have changed ```clearDB``` for ```JawsDB Maria``` because this one uses MySQL 8.0. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea aligning the development and deployment versions. It significantly helps.